# Apache - serve from another directory and set GET parameter or raise flag in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, localization, internationalization

I have a site whose language can be changed via a GET parameter:

```
http://example.com/project/             // English version
http://example.com/project/?lang=de     // German version
```

---

Is there a way to make it serve the German version from a different path? For example:

```
http://example.com/project-de/
http://example.com/project-de/page.php
```

Responds as if the requests were:

```
http://example.com/project/?lang=de
http://example.com/project/page.php?lang=de
```

If it can't be done with GET parameters, is there some sort of way to raise a PHP flag that would control the language of the site?

**All** my PHP pages `require` a common `config.php` file. By default, my language variable is set to `en`. When I go to `/project-de`, I want it to serve files from `/project` **and** raise some kind of flag that tells `config.php` to change the language to `de` before including my site files. **Is there a way to do that?**

Comment: Look into `htaccess` on how to do it or try session or cookies.

Comment: Use `session` to set lang.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

You can setcookie into user browser. You can read cookie from client(user) browser and you can easily set the language reading from cookie.